# In what sense is the sequence $(0,1,2,0,1,2,\ldots)$ convergent?

Tags: convergence-divergence, terminology

In what sense is the sequence $(0,1,2,0,1,2,\ldots)$ convergent?

A problem I'm working on needs a concept of convergence which understands the fact that this sequence extended infinitely is convergent - at least in the sense that it is stable and orbits a fixed point.

The name may not be "convergence".

I can of course engineer something but I presume there is some accepted terminology I can use.

For example I want to describe that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left((1-2^{-n})+ (n\mod3)\right)$$ converges upon an orbit centred on the number $2$

Comment: There are three convergent subsequences. One converges to 0, the other converges to 1 and…

Comment: Thanks @LiChunMin that's exactly the answer I need.  The problem's a little more complicated in that there are infinitely many subsequences... every one of which converges, but since there are infinitely many, there are new subsequences constantly appearing.

Comment: Aha. Sure there are infinitely many convergent subsequence there. For each n, make put n zeros there and make the tail to be all one… That lead me to think of this question: are there only countably many convergent subsequences?

Comment: @LiChunMin In a [sequential space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space) like $\mathbb R$, the set of limits of subsequences is the same as the set of "accumulation points" of the sequence. See my answer for some relevant links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of "[accumulation points](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/accumulation-points-of-a-sequence)" (sometimes "[cluster points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point#Types_of_limit_points)") of the first sequence is $\{0,1,2\}$ and that set for the second sequence is $\{1,2,3\}$. This is because every neighborhood of one of the numbers, say $1$, has infinitely many sequence entries in that neighborhood.

This idea of the accumulation points is closely related to other ideas of "[limit set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_set)" like [attractors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor#Mathematical_definition) and [limit cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_cycle).

Answer (score 2):

I would not use the word "convergent" in **any** sense!  This sequence is "periodic" with period 3.

Comment: The second sequence is not periodic, yet it has an important relationship to convergence since there is a finite set of limits of convergent subsequences.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the already defined [Cesàro summability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation), and sort of modify it to fit your needs. Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be your sequence. We can define a sequence to be **Cesàro convergent** if and only if

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \in \mathbb R$$
That is, if the limit above exists, the sequence is **Cesàro convergent**.

Notice, in your case, the limit above converges to $1$, since that is the average value of your sequence. So, in this sense, the sequence is "Cesàro convergent around 1".